# Can I use "Says you!" In reply to a compliment or an insult?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

I've heard speakers using that very expression ("Says you") in response to a compliment, which makes it closer to saying "Look who is talking" or "You're the one who deserves it". A quick search, though, only led me to the meaning "that's only your opinion" in an expression of disagreement or denial.

Comment: Could you specify in which country and by whom you heard this expression used? I am unfamiliar with it, I'm thinking it could be a generational or a dialect difference.

Comment: I've heard and used (when I was a teenager and in my 20s):  "**Says who?**"

Comment: Normal in the UK, also Australia if slightly old fashioned and definitely informal. Sometimes written 'Sez you!' Also 'Sez who?' is heard. See [sez](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sez) in Collins Dctionary

Comment: I have never heard "says you" in response to a compliment. Normally the phrase is used to express disagreement, it basically means "that's just your opinion, and your opinion is wrong".

Comment: @Mari-LouA She's Australian. She posted a photo on IG and used this expression to respond to sb telling her she looks good. She's in her twenties.

Comment: I think it probably comes across better in speech, I would avoid writing "Says you!" but that's coming from me who's 55...yikes!

Comment: I’m gonna go with @KannE’s feigned humility then.  They say everyone is their own worst critic so she probably sees all her own flaws in the picture, but she obviously liked it enough to decide to post it.

Comment: Speaking as an Aussie, says you is fine for both an insult and a compliment but generally not heard all too frequently. It means the same as “that’s rich, coming from you” in both positive and negative contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re Australian then yes definitely, other regions maybe not. ‘Says you!’ In response to a compliment or insult is effectively reversing the insult/compliment, and is similar to saying “that’s rich coming from you” but without the inherent negativity.

However, “says you!” is interpreted in different regions to mean “so says you” or “you say that (but I don’t)”. So be careful where you use this because the meaning appears to be highly regional.

Comment: I am Australian but don't recall having heard "says you" in response to a compliment.

Comment: @nnnnnn most likely place you’ll see it or hear it in my experience is women complimenting each other - think responses to compliments on social media. I’m sure it’s not super common and I don’t hear it a great deal but it’s definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

I've grown up with people using the phrase 'Says you' after a compliment. I personally have interpreted it as 'Look at you,you're so pretty'. So if somebody says this phrase to you ('Says you') ask them in which way they mean it instead of thinking that they're being mean.

Comment: Where and when did you grow up? The expression seems geographically specific.